# Every cluster point of a sequence is a sequential cluster point, but the converse is not true.

Tags: real-analysis

This is part of theory from the Real Analysis book by Schramm.

The definition of a sequential cluster point as given
**A point c is a sequential cluster point of (xn) if {n, xn ∈ (c-ε,c+ε)} is infinite for each ε > 0.**

There was a theorem that was proven earlier that "***If c is a cluster point of {xn}, there is a subsequence  converging to c.***"
which also implies that if c is a cluster point of a sequence it is a sequential cluster point.

Can someone please explain me why and how the converse will fail ?

P.S : I am self learning Real Analysis(a beginner) so I am not at all good in real analysis.
So please use simple terms(or explain them) for the answer.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE! You should try typing and formatting Mathematics using MathJaX. You can find tutorial here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Also, from what you have written, are you wanting to write that a point $c$ is a sequential cluster point of a sequence if there is a subsequence converging to the point?

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh Yes That's what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a sequence $\left\lbrace x_n \right\rbrace$ where $x_n = \left( -1 \right)^n$. The sequence goes like this $\left( -1, 1, -1, 1, \cdots \right)$. Now, from the definition of a "sequential cluster point", $-1$ and $1$ are both sequential cluster points of this sequence, because there are subsequences, namely the constant sequences $-1$ and $1$ which converge to the respective sequential cluster points. However, this sequence does not have any real number as its cluster point.

So, here the converse fails. Because we can find a sequence and a point which is a sequential cluster point of the sequence but it is not the cluster point for the sequence.